# Why does Celery NOT throw an Exception when the underlying task throws one

Tags: python, exception, celery

Celery doesn't seem to be handling exceptions properly.

If I have task:

```
def errorTest():
    raise Exception()
```

and then I call

```
r = errorTest.delay()
In [8]: r.result

In [9]: r.state
Out[9]: 'PENDING'
```

And it will hang like this indefinitely.

Going and checking the logs shows that the error IS getting thrown in the task (and if you want the message, ask), and I know that the backend and everything is set up properly because other tasks just work and return results correctly.

Is there something funky that I need to do to catch exceptions in Celery?

/Celery version is 3.0.13, broker is RabbitMQ running on my local machine

Comment: What do you want to happen when the exception is raised?

Comment: Maybe the results aren't being sent?  Are you sure the worker has the result backend enabled?  E.g. Some times people leave old worker processes running that doesn't have the new configuration.

Comment: In theory, r.state should be "FAILURE" and r.result should be the thrown exception just like it says in the celery docs.

And I know that Celery results backend is running because any successful process will return the result, but it only happens on exceptions

Comment: Well, in this case no state has been updated.  pending is the default state for any task_id, it doesn't tell you if the task exists or not as no state is written when the task is sent.  It just assumes that if you know the task_id, and there's no state for the task that it's in flight.

Comment: So even after the task crashes, it's expected behavior that the task will never ever return the fact that it failed (even though I left my computer on overnight out of curiousity to see if it would ever return), and that any calls to task.get() will hang indefinitely?  

Any chance you can put that in the tutorial docs in big flashing glittery letters, because that is non-obvious behavior.  (In fact, if I remember correctly, it contradicts the docs, which say that r.state should be failed, and r.result the thrown exception)

Comment: @KevinMeyer no, I said that because you were not using `result.get()` in your example.  Celery definitely does update state when a task raises an exception.  Both the client and the worker processing the task must use the same result backend, otherwise it won't work

Comment: Check out my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694771/why-does-celery-not-throw-an-exception-when-the-underlying-task-throws-one/51517810#51517810

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define an [`on_failure`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.on_failure) function in your `Task` subclass to handle them correctly.  If you're just looking to find out what happened you can setup [error email notifications](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#std:setting-CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS) that will send you the stack trace in your celery config.

Note: As of v4 Celery no [longer supports sending emails](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/whatsnew-4.0.html?highlight=retry#features-removed-for-simplicity).

Comment: Does this solve the problem of the hanging?  Because a week ago, this was not hanging on the same computer with the same test on the same code base.

Comment: And testing says: "Yes." (Odd that defining an on_failure method that does bupkis solves the problem, whereas using the default one causes crashing.  )

Comment: I'm not sure if it changes it but in the base Task class the on_failure method is just a NotImplementedYet exception.  There's a few different ways that you can play with it but that was the easiest one that I could figure out.

Comment: The on_failure handler lets you define additional actions to do when a task raises an exception, it's irrelevant to the result being updated, in fact it's called after the result is sent so it will not have any effect on the result/state.  Note that no result will be sent if the task has the ignore_result flag set, and the most common source of missing results is to have a broken worker process that is not sending results properly.  If you have started a worker on top of the old broken one the errors are usual seen in round-robin.

Answer (score 41):

If you are running Celery with the CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER set to True, then make sure you include this line in your settings too:

```
CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS = True
```

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-eager-propagates-exceptions

Comment: If you want to just temporarily turn on exception propagation for debugging you can also set throw to True when calling a task with apply().  I.e name_of_task_to_debug.apply(throw=True)

Comment: As of Celery 4.2, this value seems to have been renamed to `CELERY_TASK_EAGER_PROPAGATES`, as per http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

Going to make @primalpython's answer more explicit.

This will fail:

```
@task
def error():
    raise Exception
```

Input/Output:

```
In [7]: r = error.delay()

In [8]: print r.state
Out[8]: 'PENDING'

In [9]: print r.result
Out[9]: None
```

This will succeed:

```
@task
def error():
    raise Exception

    def on_failure(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Input/Output:

```
In [7]: r = error.delay()

In [8]: print r.state
Out[8]: 'FAILURE'

In [9]: print r.result
Out[9]: Exception()
```

Comment: This is unlikely to have any effect, you must double check that you do not have any left-over workers running.  You cannot define a on_failure handler this way, you must extend the underlying task class to add this.

Comment: Dude, it worked.  Something with the odd combo of your code and my code made it work.

Comment: The on_failure you added in that code block cannot possibly have any effect, as it's not executed or even reachable from anywhere. It's like saying that it worked because you added a comment to the code :) I think my explanation of a broken worker process is more likely, and it's a very common pitfall (should have some way to detect this and warn users).  Btw, you can run the `sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues -p $your_vhost name consumers | grep celery' to see the number of workers consuming from the default queue.

Comment: It works. I don't know why, it makes no sense, I did not step into the code with the debugger to see what is going on, the `on_failure` function is never even called, but it works. Yay for celery.

Comment: is `on_failure` supposed to be defined **within** the task body? This may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the easiest way to do this is to pass in a reference to a task class to use when you create your new Celery application.

In one module define the task class to use by default:

```
from celery.app.task import Task
import logging

logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

class LoggingTask(Task):
  def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
      kwargs={}
      if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
         kwargs['exc_info']=exc
      logger.error('Task % failed to execute', task_id, **kwargs)
      super().on_failure(exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo)
```

When you define your app, reference the module (note, it's a string reference you provide..):

```
from celery import Celery

app=Celery('my_project_name', task_cls='task_package.module_name:LoggingTask')
```

From that point forward, if no task class is specifically provided, the LoggingTask will be used - thereby allowing you to effect *all* existing tasks (that use the default) rather than having to modify each one.  This also means you can use the @shared_task decorator as normal..